# PHP redirection not working on login page

Tags: php, session, header, syntax-error, session-variables

I have created a login.php page and used php code to check the credentials from database. If the entered credentials are incorrect it shows the error (thats perfect). But if the entered credentials are correct, it do not redirect to the index.php page.

**Kindly check the php code of login.php:**

```php
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
        session_start();
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
        $result = mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());
        $num_row = mysql_num_rows($result);
        $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
        if( $num_row > 0 ) {
            $_SESSION['id']=$row['user_id'];
            header('location:index.php');
        }
        else{ ?>
            <div class="alert alert-danger">Access Denied</div> 
            <?php
        }
    }
?>
```

**Kindle refer the error screenshots:**

[image]

I think user_id from database is not properly assigned to $_SESSION['id']. I would really appreciate if anyone can guide to to solve these errors.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you write some html before the header ? (this code is include form something else ? like a layout ?)

Comment: And avoid using the monstrous `mysql_*`.

Comment: header needs to be put before any output to the client. Either use mysqli, or PDO.

Comment: why are you setting a session var - `$_SESSION['id']` - after your `header()`? If your redirect was successful, it would never be set.

Comment: Are you getting the "headers already sent" error?

Comment: `header('location:index.php');` problem in here. this will immediately change your  location before set `SESSION`

Comment: did you use any encoding in database to store the password or is it simple text (varchar)?. And assign the value to the `$_SESSION['id']` before using the `header()` function.

Comment: @Sean Calling `header()` doesn't stop code execution, so the session will be set almost always.

Comment: Hello Sourabh, I have not used any encoding to store passwords

Comment: This code is working perfectly offline on wamp, but when I uploaded it on server, this issue was their.

Comment: Thank you for your comments guys. I have tried your suggestion, but it did not solved the issue. I think user_id from database is not properly assigned to $_SESSION['id']. Kindly revert me if this is the issue.

Comment: I am getting a warning: Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at C:\wamp\www\mega-library\framework\login.php:91) in C:\wamp\www\mega-library\framework\login.php on line 101

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message shows exactly the problem: at the given line of the given php file, output has been produced already. After starting output, you cannot set headers any more because they have to be set before any document data.

In order to solve the problem, check what output is produced at the given line. You may be able to remove it. If not, you may be able to use buffering. If you direct output to a buffer, you can add headers at any time.

Check http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php to learn about how to use buffering. It is easy: you just turn it on at the beginning, then flush the buffer when you're done.

Note that the session id will not be automatically appended to an URL in header(). You will have to do that manually. Also note that according to the RFC, the URL actually requires to be absolute (although a relative URL will usually work). So use:

```
header("Location: ". $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] ."/index.php?". SID);
```

Also see http://php.net/manual/en/session.idpassing.php and http://php.net/manual/en/session.constants.php for details.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion, still login page is not redirecting to the index.php page. Is my above code storing value from to session variable correctly?

Comment: I complemented my answer with info about using the session id with the location header which was missing in my original text.

Comment: I just noticed that in your SQL, you select "username" while later you use "user_id" to assign the session id. This seems incorrect to me. Anyway, it is not good practice to use the user id as the session id, but I assume you are doing so for testing purposes only? Also, $row is not used before. My guess ist that you should use `$_SESSION['id']=$result[0]['username']`

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked the fetch_array, so it should be $row[0]['username']

Answer (score 0):

if you are getting "headers already sent" error then redirection wont work.
try changing ur code like below,

```html
if( $num_row > 0 ) {
            $_SESSION['id']=$row['user_id'];
            echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="0; URL=index.php">';    
           
}
```

Comment: Hi Pradeep, I thank you for your answer. I tried your code, but it didnt worked. I think their is an issue in line: $_SESSION['id']=$row['user_id'];

I think the user_id is not assigned to $_SESSION['id']

Can you please help with that?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the code to look like this ( note $_SESSION is before header() ):

```
if( $num_row > 0 ) {
    $_SESSION['id']=$row['user_id'];
    header('location:index.php');
}
```

Comment: Hi Michal, I tried your suggestion but it now worked. I think user_id from database is not properly assigned to $_SESSION['id'].